# How to find the intersection and symmetric difference of the same ID in two dataframes using pyspark

Tags: pyspark

How to find the intersection and symmetric difference of the same ID in two dataframes using pyspark.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbL1w.png)
thanks~

Comment: please, do not post code or result as images. you can use MD to format properly array and code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `semi` and `anti` joins. See below code implementation for details -

**Input dataframes** -

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data=[(100,1,115),(200,2,286),(300,3,72),(400,4,819)], schema= ["userId", "movieId", "score"])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data=[(100,1,115),(200,2,286),(500,3,72),(600,4,819)], schema= ["userId", "movieId", "score"])
```

**Resultant Dataframes:** `result1`-

```
result1 = df1.join(df2, df1["userId"] == df2["userId"], how ="semi")
result1.show()

+------+-------+-----+
|userId|movieId|score|
+------+-------+-----+
|   100|      1|  115|
|   200|      2|  286|
+------+-------+-----+
```

**Resultant Dataframes:** `result2`-

```
result21 = df1.join(df2, df1["userId"] == df2["userId"], how ="anti")
result22 = df2.join(df1, df2["userId"] == df1["userId"], how ="anti")

result2 = result21.unionAll(result22)
result2.show()

+------+-------+-----+
|userId|movieId|score|
+------+-------+-----+
|   300|      3|   72|
|   400|      4|  819|
|   500|      3|   72|
|   600|      4|  819|
+------+-------+-----+
```

You can go through below official Spark for details about both `join` types to have a better idea -

- [Spark Semi Join](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-join.html#semi-join)
- [Spark Anti Join](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-join.html#anti-join)

Comment: If the answer helped to solve the problem please check the ✓ symbol next to the answer. Upvote too, if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Join depends on the columns you want to join for. If you are interested in the intersection and difference, [substract](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.subtract.html) and [intersect](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.intersect.html) are safer because they take into consideration the row in all the columns of both DataFrames

```
df1.intersect(df2).show()

# +------+-------+-----+
# |userId|movieId|score|
# +------+-------+-----+
# |   100|      1|  115|
# |   200|      2|  286|
# +------+-------+-----+


df1.subtract(df2).union(df2.subtract(df1)).sort("userId").show()

# +------+-------+-----+
# |userId|movieId|score|
# +------+-------+-----+
# |   300|      3|   72|
# |   400|      4|  819|
# |   500|      3|   72|
# |   600|      4|  819|
# +------+-------+-----+
```